# Changing password in OpenVAS command line

Tags: password, openvas, gsa

I've been trying to find the right OAP command for changing the password for OpenVAS users.
It is possible to change it the Greenbone Security Assistent interface. But i can't find it for doing it through CLI.

```
-c, --command=<command>  OAP command (e.g. add_user, remove_user, list_users)
```

OAP command does allow to add or remove user but i can't find the command to edit user settings.

Comment: http://www.openvas.org/oap-1-1.html#command_modify_user seems relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can change the password via command line. However the following script does so by changing the password hash directly in the users file.

Create a file containing the script in the following link and execute it:  http://lists.wald.intevation.org/pipermail/openvas-discuss/2013-January/004879.html

Works fine on CentOS 6.